# how to send firebase mobile events from sdk to custom http endpoint?

Tags: firebase, events, google-analytics, webhooks

We use firebase to send mobile log events, which goes by default to google analytics.

We want to get those events also in our own web server (the purpose is to send the events to kafka)

Is there any way to "fork" the log event both to google analytics and some webhook (or at least only to the webhook)?

Comment: did you find any way to do this?

Comment: nope, just move to use another SDK like rudderstack to route the events

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I read about rudderstack, how good is it?